# Launch 7Digital Music Store on BlackBerry Playbook

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-webworks, blackberry-playbook, 7digital

Is it at all possible to launch the 7Digital music store on the BlackBerry Playbook using the WebWorks SDK. I would like to open the store on an album page for a given band. The  [Invoke API](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/webworks/api/blackberry.invoke.html) appears not to offer the store as a launch option.